# Volatile HashMap Not Updating Outside of Thead

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, volatile

so I have a HashMap that is declared in class level like so:

```
private static volatile HashMap<String, ArrayList>String>> map =
     new HashMap<String, ArrayList>String>>();
```

I have several threads updating the same map and the threads are declared in the class level like so:

```
private class UpdateThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update map here
            // map actually gets updated here
        }
}
```

But after the threads exit:

```
for (FetchSKUsThread thread : listOfThreads) {
        thread.start();
}
for (FetchSKUsThread thread : listOfThreads) {
        try {
           thread.join();
           // map not updated anymore :-[
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Why are the map changes that are occuring inside the thread not persisting after the thread is done? I've decalred the map static and volatile already...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Marking a `HashMap` as `volatile` doesn't make the map thread-safe.  You should probably be using `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Yeah, and presumably `map` should be `final` instead of `volatile`.

Comment: `volatile` applies only to the _reference_ that points to the `HashMap`, not to the `HashMap` contents.

Comment: The contents of the HashMap are already volatile, and value updates are actually thread-safe. This pattern isn't necessarily broken, but it probably is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are the map changes that are occurring inside the thread not persisting after the thread is done? I've declared the map static and volatile already...

It depends highly on how you are updating the map.

```
// update map here -- what's happening here?
```

As @Louis points out, if multiple threads are updating the same map instance, `volatile` won't help you and you should be using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  As @Gerhard points out, `volatile` is only protecting the updating of the `HashMap` *reference* and not the innards of the map itself.  You need to fully lock the map if the threads are updating it in parallel or use a concurrent map.

However, if each thread is *replacing* the map with a new map then the `volatile` method would work.  Then again, each thread may be overwriting the central map because of race conditions.

If you show us your update code, we should be able to explain it better.

Comment: Thanks! It was actually a variable scoping problem where I had the volatile hashmap redeclared sub class level. and You're right I just read up on ConcurrentHashMap and realized that that is what I need since each thread only inserts more key-value pairs into the map. Thank You! And sorry for leaving the update code out, I thought that would just be extra code for you guys to read

Comment: Np @ThomasSo.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

The keyowrd *volatile* only makes the *reference* to the HashMap visible to all threads.

If you want to access a HashMap in several threads, you need to use a synchronized map. The easiest choices are using `java.util.Hashtable` or using `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`. The *volatile* declaration is useless in your case, since your variable is initialized at the beginning.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is better than those options. Other than that this is a good answer.

Comment: Yeah, `Hashtable` especially is very old and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `volatile` apply only to the variable you are declaring.

In your case, the variable that holds your reference to `map` is volatile, and so the JVM will go to lengths to assure that changes you make to the reference contained by `map` are visible to other threads.

However, the object referred to by `map` is not covered by any such guarantee and in order for changes to any object or any object graph to be viewed by other threads, you will need to establish a happens-before relationship.  With mutable state objects, this usually means synchronizing on a lock or using a thread safe object designed for concurrency.  Happily, in your case, a high-performance Map implementation designed for concurrent access is part of the Java library: `ConcurrentHashMap'.